# Pandas - groupby multiple columns and keep multiple columns-

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
    action  person_id                       frame_no        path
0   boxing  person12_boxing_d2_uncomp.avi   image_0128.jpg  ../../../datasets/kth/train/boxing/person12_bo...
1   boxing  person12_boxing_d2_uncomp.avi   image_0129.jpg  ../../../datasets/kth/train/boxing/person12_bo...
2   walking person13_boxing_d2_uncomp.avi   image_0130.jpg  ../../../datasets/kth/train/walking/person13_b...
3   walking person13_boxing_d2_uncomp.avi   image_0131.jpg  ../../../datasets/kth/train/walking/person13_b...
4   running person13_boxing_d2_uncomp.avi   image_0132.jpg  ../../../datasets/kth/train/running/person13_b.
```

and I am trying to merge rows that have the same `person_id`. Rows with the same `person_id` will definitely have the same `action`. This is what I currently have

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data_filtered, columns=["action","person_id","frame_no","path"])
#df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(["action","person_id"])['frame_no'].apply(list)).reset_index()
df.head()
```

but the data frame loses the `path` column. I'm not sure how to tell pandas to group the remaining columns and searching on google has not helped because I don't even know what to search for. Sorry if this has been repeatedly asked.

@ Aditya

I have tried

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(["action","person_id"])[['frame_no', 'path']].apply(list)).reset_index()
```

but this is what I get

```
    action  person_id                       0
0   boxing  person12_boxing_d2_uncomp.avi   [frame_no, path]
1   running person13_boxing_d2_uncomp.avi   [frame_no, path]
2   walking person13_boxing_d2_uncomp.avi   [frame_no, path]
```

Comment: You don't want to just `drop_duplicates(subset=['person_id'])`?

Comment: If you want to get all the paths as well, just include it with [['frame_no', 'path']]; No he doesn't want to drop the record's, he want to combine them into one I think (since same personIDs have different images, hence the intuition for the above remark)

Comment: @Aditya, I have tried what you suggested before posting the thread but it did not give me the result i had hoped for. I have edited my post to include the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# pd.__version__ == 0.25.1
d=[['hello',1,'GOOD','long.kw'],
   ['chipotle',2,'GOOD','bingo'],
   ['hello',3,"BAD", "lm"]]
t=pd.DataFrame(data=d, columns=['A','B','C','D'])
```

Output is

```
t.groupby('A')[['B','C']].agg(lambda x: tuple(x)).applymap(list)
               B            C
A
chipotle     [2]       [GOOD]
hello     [1, 3]  [GOOD, BAD]
```

Comment: Cool ! Thank you !. I just had to modify it df = df.groupby(["action","person_id"])[['frame_no', 'path']].agg(lambda x: tuple(x)).applymap(list).reset_index() and I now have the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Only change [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) to [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) for convert each column to list:

```
print (df)
    action                      person_id        frame_no         path
0   boxing  person12_boxing_d2_uncomp.avi  image_0128.jpg  person12_bo
1   boxing  person12_boxing_d2_uncomp.avi  image_0129.jpg  person12_bo
2  walking  person13_boxing_d2_uncomp.avi  image_0130.jpg   person13_b
3  walking  person13_boxing_d2_uncomp.avi  image_0131.jpg   person13_b
4  running  person13_boxing_d2_uncomp.avi  image_0132.jpg   person13_b

df = df.groupby(["action","person_id"])['frame_no', 'path'].agg(list)
print (df)
                                                               frame_no  \
action  person_id                                                         
boxing  person12_boxing_d2_uncomp.avi  [image_0128.jpg, image_0129.jpg]   
running person13_boxing_d2_uncomp.avi                  [image_0132.jpg]   
walking person13_boxing_d2_uncomp.avi  [image_0130.jpg, image_0131.jpg]   

                                                             path  
action  person_id                                                  
boxing  person12_boxing_d2_uncomp.avi  [person12_bo, person12_bo]  
running person13_boxing_d2_uncomp.avi                [person13_b]  
walking person13_boxing_d2_uncomp.avi    [person13_b, person13_b]
```